# Rental car insurance in the UK

Tags: uk, car-rentals, insurance

I will be visiting the UK for two weeks later this year and renting a car. I would rather not pay the extortionate insurance rates that the rental company will charge me for this. I have a valid UK drivers license (I used to live there).

My own vehicle insurance only covers rental cars in the US and Canada. I am aware of credit cards that cover rental car insurance, but I haven't found one with an annual fee of less than $120, which would mean I wouldn't save much.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This probably depends on what company you plan to hire your car from. For instance, [according to Avis, they already include mandatory insurance cover in the quoted price and anything above that can be bought as 'additional cover'](http://www.avis.co.uk/ProductsServices/Additional-Products/Additional-Cover/Insurance-explained).

> When renting a car, it is essential you are properly protected
>   according to UK law and your own requirements.  When you book an Avis
>   rental car, the price you are quoted includes basic level of cover
>   needed should you be involved in an accident. In the UK, this means
>   you are automatically covered for:
>
> - Third Party Cover
> - Vehicle Damage Cover
> - Vehicle Theft Cover

Avis does charge anywhere between £5-15 per day for additional cover depending on the level of additional protection you buy, but you don't *need* to.

Similarly check with whichever car rental you are planning to do business with. They may have already factored in the cost into their prices.

Comment: I don't know where the quote you posted comes from. It isn't from the page you linked to. In fact that page says of the mandatory cover:"Does not Cover:Theft or attempted theft of the vehicle;Theft of personal belongings from the vehicle;Death or injury to the driver;
Damage to the rental vehicle".

Comment: You said you wanted 'insurance' - you didn't specify what for! I was pointing out the fact the minimum mandatory cover is already accounted for in the price. Also check the 'Vehicular Damage Cover' and 'Vehicle Theft Protection' sections on that same page.

Comment: Did you mean to imply that the minimum level of insurance covers damage to the rental vehicle and theft of the rental vehicle? That's what I took your answer to mean, and it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: No. Minimum legal requirement in UK is 'Legal Liability, Third Party and Public Liability Cover'; basically, if you end up damaging/hurting anyone else. Additionally, included in the price you also get Vehicle Damage Cover and Vehicle Theft cover, without additional charge. Perhaps I didn't phrase it clearly enough or you didn't read the rest of the section on the page I linked to. 'Additional cover' is a separate section on the page, after a section break.

Comment: You do seem to be right. At least the basic quote for the car seemed to include the vehicle damage insurance. If you make a small edit to your answer I will remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy collision and loss damage waiver  cover for rental vehicles from insurers other than the rental firm or your own insurer. They normally are cheaper than either of those.

Here's an example. I don't have any experience of using them though https://www.icarhireinsurance.com/insurance-information-centre/cdw-ldw-collision-loss-damage-waiver

Answer (score 0):

Third party is pretty standard when renting in uk usually is included in price , collision damage waiver is extra unless your credit card company covers it , which mine does , but only covers you in a collision , the one they get you on is the access insurance this covers you for tire damage, such as blow outs , side wall damage etc ,under carriage damage, scratches, dents, glass, wing mirrors, and car being stolen, this is pretty much the most important ,runs about 6 pounds a day , well worth it 1st time I took this out was for three weeks hire cost me $160.00 over night parking someone took my mirror off, would have cost me out of pocket 420 pounds, about 600 dollars, the rental companies charge you for time the car is off the rd plus material and labour worth checking.